# Publish app to App Store using someone else's Mac?

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I have built an app using HTML5 / JavaScript, and it works well as a mobile web app, bu tI would like to publish it to the Apple App Store.

I don't own a Macbook, so I'll be relying on using a friend's Macbook.  Will I encounter any unforeseen problems with setting up Xcode and iTunes connect etc. when the Macbook I'm using is registered with someone else?

Not having done this before, I'd prefer to get it right the first time, so I'm just wondering if anyone else has found any 'gotchas' while trying to do this?

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Thanks Jason and Aderstedt for your comments below - setting up a new user account on my friend's Mac is a good idea - that's how I'll go about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to request developer keys from your friend's Mac. This means his Mac will have the private keys in his keychain. For your own safety, you'll want to copy those private keys somewhere safe (your own flash drive, Dropbox, etc) and then delete them from your friend's Mac.

Additionally, every time you want to update your App(s) you'll need to restore these keys.

This is not counting the time you'll spend downloading and installing the developer tools if your friend doesn't already have them installed on his Mac.

Trust me, key management is not something any iOS developer enjoys and by attempting this on an "untrusted" system you're potentially opening yourself up to additional effort and/or security risks.

I'd highly recommend you look at purchasing your own Mac.

However, if that is not an optional at all, at bare minimum insist that your friend setup a new account for you. Use this account for deploying your app. After you're done, backup your entire keychain (this way you won't accidentally miss anything important), and then have your friend delete your profile. This is the safest way to do this on someone else's Mac.

See http://support.apple.com/kb/PH4077 for information about backing up your keychain on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible. I recommend creating a new user account on your friend's Mac. This will let you have your own environment separate from your friend's. All certificates and private keys will be in your personal login keychain (any provisioning profiles will be system wide, but unusable without the keys and certificates).

Instead of placing the keys and certificates on your login keychain I recommend creating another keychain and putting that stuff there. Protect that keychain with a different password.